# Multi-line placeholder in textarea with Bootstrap-Vue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'd like to have a multi-line placeholder in a textarea with Boostrap-Vue (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/). It's straightforwd to have a one-line placeholder. What about multi-line?

Trying to insert linebreaks in placeholder attr doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enter a line-break as following:

```
<b-form-textarea id="textarea1"
                 v-model="text"
                 :placeholder="'Enter something \n in more \n lines '"
                 :rows="3"
                 :max-rows="6">
</b-form-textarea>
```

This works beause without the `:` Vue will strip everything so that the prop is only a string hence the newline character will not work.